# Deploying MVC file system publish on IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, iis-7, web-deployment

I have created an MVC application in Visual Studio 2013 and I now wish to deploy this on the IIS of the server so that all employees from within the company will be able to access it via their windows login credentials.

When I run this in localhost via Visual Studio debug it works as expected but I have been trying unsuccessfully to deploy this to a network server and I am unsure of the process and would be grateful for some clarification.

I chose a file system publish from the publish options but I am unsure as to how to get this accessible as an application. I have tried adding the files via the new website wizard and tried the url of 'holidays/' which I had entered but without success. I then tried to add the same virtual directory location as an application from within this website but again this was unsuccessful.

Comment: does the server have web deploy?

Answer (score 0):

I use Web Deploy with VS. Your target server needs to also have Web Deploy:

[Installing and Configuring Web Deploy on IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy)

Once your target server is ready, you can deploy from VS. Here's a guide on doing that (you can jump right to "Publish to IIS" section if you like):

[ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis)

With Web Deploy, you can choose to publish directly or use a deployment package.   Once you are happy the publishing works locally, you have a level of confidence your publishing will work in your Live environment.

I would suggest that before you publish direct to a live environment, that you test publish it to your local machine or a test environment that has the same IIS version, and .NET Framework installed.